# Unable to extract zip file automatically while running application inside Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a zip folder, copied it inside Docker image using `Dockerfile`.

```
COPY ./ms-analytics-ivu.1.0.1.jar /deploy/
COPY plugins/* /deploy/plugins/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/plugin
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/ms-analytics.1.0.1.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/deploy/ms-analytics.1.0.1.jar","analytics","--spring.config.location=file:/deploy/config/analytics-server.yml"]
EXPOSE 8087
```

Here, the `plugins` folder contains some zip file, after running this application, zip file should automatically extract, which is not happening inside Docker image.

Comment: (Aside: in English, punctuation marks tend to be followed by a space, and not preceded by a space. This ensures that commas, full stops, colons and semi-colons (etc) cannot be pushed onto the next line, disconnecting them from the word they were part of. Hope this helps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use `ADD` instead of `COPY` according to this [post](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-add-vs-copy/) , `ADD` have the ability to automatically unpack compressed files.
here is the quote :

> Another feature of ADD is the ability to automatically unpack compressed files. If the  argument is a local file in a recognized compression format (tar, gzip, bzip2, etc) then it is unpacked at the specified  in the container's filesystem

Comment: Hi Fendi ,I changed to ADD plugins/* /deploy/plugins/ ,but still It's not unzipping zip files inside plugins folder .

Comment: oh right. .my bad.. turns out it havent support zip yet.. i guess the other options is to use multi-stage builds, like this guy here : 
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15036